# firebase.ps1 cannot be loaded because running scripts is disabled on this system

Tags: firebase

firebase sends this error if I try firebase init. can anyone please help me with this. I am new. and I don't really know much.

firebase : File C:\Users\USER\AppData\Roaming\npm\firebase.ps1 cannot be loaded because running scripts is disabled on
this system. For more information, see about_Execution_Policies at https:/go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=135170.
At line:1 char:1

- firebase init
- ```
    + CategoryInfo          : SecurityError: (:) [], PSSecurityException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : UnauthorizedAccess
  ```

Answer (score 2):

Step 1 :
open **Windows PowerShell (Run as administrator)**

Step 2 :
Type in `Get-ExecutionPolicy -List` and hit Enter.

Step 3 :
Type in `Set-ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted` and hit Enter again.

Step 4 :
Type `Y` and hit Enter.

Step 5 :
Type `Set-ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -Force` and hit Enter.